# How to show menu items automatically in android (without clicking menu button) when the layout is viewed.?

Tags: android, android-emulator

How to show menu items automatically  in android (without clicking menu button) when the layout is viewed.? I am using this code but it is not working.

```
package com.sai.menu;

import java.util.Timer;

import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.ContextMenu;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MenuInflater;

import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class ViewOptionsMenu extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    openOptionsMenu();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); 
    menu.add("Search");  
    menu.add("More");  
    return true;
}

@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  

              closeOptionsMenu();

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


 }
```

Comment: why have you provided  closeOptionsMenu();
then?

Comment: I have removed it but still it is not working.

Comment: I think only onCreateOptionsMenu() would work. There is no need of onPrepareOptionsMenu()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

openOptionsMenu() does not work if called from onCreate(). Try following instead:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    openOptionsMenu();
}
```